# Algebraic Normal Form Piccolo

Tags: symmetric, feistel-network

I'm trying to verify the claim of paper [Improved Algebraic Fault Analysis: A Case Study on Piccolo and with Applications to other
Lightweight Block Ciphers](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~zshi/publications/zhang13_improved_afa.pdf) about the numbers of equations in algebraic normal form that in one round of the Piccolo cipher. According to method in Section 4.2 is there 928 equations, but I can't understand ... I get verify only the 544 variables numbers but not the numbers of equations

I'm trying:
For each S-box is there 4 equations, then in 16 S-box by round is there 64 equations. For mix columns, using Table 3 I have 12 equations ...